# Best practice: How to persist simple data without a database in django?

Tags: python, django, persistence

I'm building a website that doesn't require a database because a REST API "is the database". (Except you don't want to be putting site-specific things in there, since the API is used by mostly mobile clients)

However there's a few things that normally would be put in a database, for example the "jobs" page. You have master list view, and the detail views for each job, and it should be easy to add new job entries. (not necessarily via a CMS, but that would be awesome)

e.g. `example.com/careers/` and `example.com/careers/77/`

I could just hardcode this stuff in templates, but that's no DRY- you have to update the master template and the detail template every time.

What do you guys think? Maybe a YAML file? Or any better ideas?
Thx

Answer (score 5):

Why not still keep it in a database? Your remote REST store is all well and funky, but if you've got local data, there's nothing (unless there's spec saying so) to stop you storing some stuff in a local db. Doesn't have to be anything v glamorous - could be sqlite, or you could have some fun with redis, etc.

Comment: I would like to stay away from databases if possible. Schema design, migrations, making sure all environments have the current schemas, big point of failure, sysadmin headaches, etc etc

Comment: Django ORM makes schema design easy, and South handles migrations pretty well... the admin interface makes a decent free CRM...

Comment: +1 for Chris L's point. And if you wanted to use redis, check out the README at http://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py to see how simple it can be (though you won't get the easy power of the Django ORM this way)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Memcachedb via the Django cache interface.

For example:

Set the cache backend as memcached in your django settings, but install/use [memcachedb](http://memcachedb.org/) instead.

Django can't tell the difference between the two because the provide the same interface (at least last time I checked).

Memcachedb is persistent, safe for multithreaded django servers, and won't lose data during server restarts, but it's just a key value store. not a complete database.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives built into the Python library are listed in the [Data Persistence](http://docs.python.org/library/persistence.html) chapter of the documentation. Still another is [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).